# Clear a section next to div using css

Tags: html, css

I need to clear a section after a div has class name last. For some reason I couldn't edit my html. I need to achieve it using  just css.

My Html code:

```
<div class="column">test<br />test</div>
<div class="column">test</div>
<div class="column">test</div>
<div class="column last">test</div>
<div class="column">test<br />test</div>
<div class="column">test</div>
<div class="column">test</div>
<div class="column last">test</div>
```

Css:

```
.column{ width:250px; margin-right:10px; float:left;}
.column.last{ margin-right:0px;}
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean "clear a selection?" What have you tried?

Comment: The div after <div class="column last"> getting overlapped with the first row. I need to clear them.

Answer (score 1):

```
.column.last:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0px;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0px;
     line-height: 0px;
 }
```

This is known as "clearfix."

Comment: I am not trying to hide this but clear the sections one after another.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have tried your edited code. But it still looks overlapped.

Answer (score -1):

Use a div to clear the float. ;)

```
.column{ width:24%; margin-right:1%;float:left;background:grey;margin-bottom:20px;}
.column.last{ margin-right:0px;}
.clear {clear:both;}


<div class="column">1<br />2</div>
<div class="column">3</div>
<div class="column">4</div>
<div class="column last">5</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="column">6<br />7</div>
<div class="column">8</div>
<div class="column">9</div>
<div class="column last">10</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/YMf2j/7

Comment: I changed the width to % to make it responsive.

Comment: -1, read the question before you answer. He can't edit the HTML. Also, percent widths is **fluid**, not **responsive**.